# remove all .col-md class from specific div with pure javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i`m trying to remove all .col-md-1 class from all child element in particular div.

```html
<div id="question123">
  <div class="panel-title">
    ....
  </div>
  
  <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="answer clearfix">
      <h3> ... </h3>
      <div class="answer clearfix">
        <ul class"question-list">
          <div class="row">
            <div class = "col-md-1">
              <li class="question-item" id="javatbd74656737">
                <div class="checkbox">...</div>
              </li>
            </div>
            <div class = "col-md-1">
              <li class="question-item" id="javatbd74656737">
                <div class="checkbox">...</div>
              </li>
            </div>
            <div class = "col-md-1">
              <li class="question-item" id="javatbd74656737">
                <div class="checkbox">...</div>
              </li>
            </div>
          </div>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

i now its deeply nested, but that is what i got from a dynamically generated html. i have to somehow access this particular question div. and delete the .col-md-1 from all the child div.

thanks for help !

Comment: Which "particular div"? What have you tried so far?

Comment: note that you need to actually use li's within a ul - just having a pile of divs inside a ul is not semantically correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the the find() and removeClass methods for that.

```
$('#parentElement').find('.col-md-1').removeClass('col-md-1');
```

Comment: `removeClass` doesn't require the class selector, and so can be changed to `removeClass('col-md-1')`

Answer (score 0):

you can use jQuery `removeClass()` function for this..

```js
$('.question-list .col-md-1').removeClass('col-md-1');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="question123">
      <div class="panel-title">
        ....
      </div>
      
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="answer clearfix">
          <h3> ... </h3>
          <div class="answer clearfix">
            <ul class"question-list">
              <div class="row">
                <div class = "col-md-1">
                  ....
                </div>
                <div class = "col-md-1">
                  ....
                </div>
                <div class = "col-md-1">
                  ....
                </div>
              </div>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For a non-jQuery approach - you can get all the divs with that class using querySelectorAll and then remove the class.

```
var elements= document.querySelectorAll('.question-list .col-md-1');
elements.forEach(function(el){
   el.classList.remove('col-md-1');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Get all the elements inside your `#question123` and your `.question-list` and use `removeClass` for removing the class

```js
$('#question123 .question-list .col-md-1').removeClass('col-md-1');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="question123">
  <div class="panel-title">
    ....
  </div>
  
  <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="answer clearfix">
      <h3> ... </h3>
      <div class="answer clearfix">
        <ul class="question-list">
          <div class="row">
            <div class = "col-md-1">
              ....
            </div>
            <div class = "col-md-1">
              ....
            </div>
            <div class = "col-md-1">
              ....
            </div>
          </div>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```